# Group Theory Proof using order of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I can't figure out how to get started on this proof.

> Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group that contains at least three order-3 elements. Prove that 9 divides the order of $G$. Hint: Prove $G$ contains a subgroup of order 9.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the set of all elements of $G$ whose order divides $3.$ First, prove that this is a subgroup. Second, prove that its order is a power of $3.$ Third, prove that its order is at least $4.$